# Execute unix command using Mono?

Tags: mono

Is there a way to execute a unix command using Mono?

```
$ mono --version:
Mono JIT compiler version 2.4.4 (Debian 2.4.4~svn151842-1ubuntu4.1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC)
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  x86
Disabled:      none`
```

Comment: Why would it be different from how you'd do it anywhere else in C#? Have you tried creating a `Process` and then calling `.Start` ?

Comment: not that the Process class wouldn't work with your version of mono, but I would like to warn you that version 2.4 of Mono is *ancient*. That is all

Comment: Somethings you just can't control - I'm stuck using 2.4 w/ Ubuntu 10.04...

Answer (score 0):

Calling Execute() as described here: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/excute-linux-command-under-mono-C-td1533563.html worked.